# Оптимизация кода

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM ft_user
JOIN ft_obl ON subobl IN (ft_obl.id, ft_obl.parent, 999)
JOIN ft_otr ON subotr IN (ft_otr.id, ft_otr.parent)
JOIN ft_ttopic ON ft_ttopic.tpobl IN (ft_obl.id, 999) AND ft_ttopic.tpotr = ft_otr.id
GROUP BY ft_user.uid, ft_ttopic.tid
```

Отображает строки 0 - 29 ( 1,460 всего, запрос занял 34.7807 сек.)

Попробую описать подробее:

```
SELECT * FROM ft_user
JOIN ft_obl ON subobl IN (ft_obl.id, ft_obl.parent, 999)
```

К юзерам добавляем список областей, `на_что_подписался_юзер`
таблица областей и городов, если это область то parent=0,
если город то parent указывает в какой это области

```
id| name       |parent
2 | Московская |0
4 | Москва     |2
6 | Киевская   |0
8 | Киев       |6

JOIN ft_otr ON subotr IN (ft_otr.id, ft_otr.parent)
```

Добавляем отрасли по той же схеме

```
JOIN ft_ttopic ON ft_ttopic.tpobl IN (ft_obl.id, 999) AND ft_ttopic.tpotr = ft_otr.id
\+ темы
GROUP BY ft_user.uid, ft_ttopic.tid
```

Схемы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ft_user` (
`uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`umail` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
`uobl` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`uotr` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`subobl` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`subotr` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1315 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ft_obl` (
`id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`parent` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=527 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ft_otr` (
`id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`parent` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ft_otr_opis` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=491 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ft_ttopic` (
`tid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tpobl` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`tpotr` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`tid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=510 ;
```

отредактированный код

```
SELECT *
FROM ft_user u
JOIN ft_ttopic t
JOIN ft_tpost ON t.tid = ft_tpost.ptid
JOIN ft_obl ON u.subobl = ft_obl.id
JOIN ft_otr ON u.subotr = ft_otr.id
WHERE (
    t.tpobl = u.subobl OR 999 IN ( u.subobl, t.tpobl ) 
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 from ft_obl ob WHERE
        ( ob.id = t.tpobl AND ob.parent = u.subobl )
        OR
        ( u.subobl = ob.id AND ob.parent = t.tpobl )
    )
) AND (
    t.tpotr = u.subotr OR 999 IN (u.subotr, t.tpotr ) 
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 from ft_otr ot WHERE
        ( ot.id = t.tpotr AND ot.parent = u.subotr )
        OR
        ( u.subotr = ot.id AND ot.parent = t.tpotr )
    )
) AND tstart > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( curdate() -INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: группировка с какой целью??? 

весь смысл запроса, как я понимаю: получить топики по областям и отраслям на которые подписан юзер?

Comment: Дописал схемы, Обновленный вариант стал работать еще быстрее но та же ситуация:
Отображает строки 0 - 29 ( 6,989 всего, запрос занял 0.0487 сек.)

Comment: Посмотрите логику запроса - м.б. ваш был не верным??

P.S -  так-же как вариант, мой - менее зависим от ссылочной целостности

Так-же не очень ясны диапазоны ( ваши, когда вы добавляете логику к цифрам ) значений `ft_obl.parent` и `ft_otr.parent`, т.к. возможны проблемы в данных сравнениях:  `ft_otr.parent` = u.subotr и  `ft_obl.parent = u.subobl`

Comment: Такое не возможно) посмотрите запросы...

Опять-же - вы можете что-то не договаривать по схемам, и дело в этом

Comment: обновил код, т.к. надо добавить области и отрасли на что подписан юзер, хотя вообще желательно добавить:  
область, город, отрасль, вид.  
Отображает строки 0 - 29 ( 6,989 всего, запрос занял 0.9163 сек.)  
Хотя phpmyadmin выдал ответ только через несколько минут

Comment: еще один странный глюк, почему то выбирать все быстрее чем определенные поля  
SELECT *  
Отображает строки 0 - 29 ( 137 всего, запрос занял 0.3873 сек.)
SELECT u.umail, t.ttema, t.tend, ft_tpost.ptext, ft_obl.name, ft_obl.parent, ft_otr.name, ft_otr.parent  
Отображает строки 0 - 29 ( 137 всего, запрос занял 42.9929 сек.)  
методом исключений выяснил что это происходит из за поля ft_tpost.ptext, даже если его заменить на ft_tpost.*

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте tstart, не знаю из какой таблицы

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте отказаться от IN в пользу прямых сравнений ( a = c or a = b )...

UPD: пересмотрите свою группировку, скорее всего она нужна на более раннем ( меньше join ) этапе

UPD2: Попробуйте так:

```
select *
from
  ft_user u,
  ft_ttopic t
where
  (
    u.subobl = 999 or
    t.tpobl = 999 or
    t.tpobl = u.subobl or
    exists (
      select 1
      from
        ft_obl
      where
        ft_obl.parent = u.subobl and
        ft_obl.id = t.tpobl
    )
  ) and
  (
    t.tpotr = u.subotr or
    exists (
      select 1
      from
        ft_otr
      where
        ft_otr.parent = u.subotr and
        ft_otr.id = t.tpotr
    )
  )
```

Проверочные данные:

```
select *
from
  ( select 1 as uid, 2 as subobl, 1 as subotr ) u,
  ( select 1 as tid, 8 as tpobl, 1 as tpotr ) t
where
  (
    u.subobl = 999 or
    t.tpobl = 999 or
    t.tpobl = u.subobl or
    exists (
      select 1
      from
        (
          select 8 as id, 6 as parent
          union all select 6, 0
          union all select 2, 0
        ) ft_obl
      where
        ft_obl.parent = u.subobl and
        ft_obl.id = t.tpobl
    )
  ) and
  (
    t.tpotr = u.subotr or
    exists (
      select 1
      from
        ( select 1 as id, 0 as parent ) ft_otr
      where
        ft_otr.parent = u.subotr and
        ft_otr.id = t.tpotr
    )
  )
```

UPD3:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM
      ft_user u,
      ft_ttopic t
    WHERE
          (
                t.tpobl = u.subobl
            OR  999 IN ( u.subobl, t.tpobl ) 
            OR  EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 from ft_obl ob
                  WHERE
                       ( ob.id = t.tpobl  AND ob.parent = u.subobl )
                    OR ( ob.id = u.subobl AND ob.parent = t.tpobl )
               )
          )
      AND (
                t.tpotr = u.subotr
            OR  999 IN ( u.subotr, t.tpotr ) 
            OR  EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 from ft_otr ot
                  WHERE
                        ( ot.id = t.tpotr  AND ot.parent = u.subotr )
                    OR  ( ot.id = u.subotr AND ot.parent = t.tpotr )
            )
          )
      AND tstart > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
  ) t,
INNER JOIN ft_tpost ON ft_tpost.ptid = t.tid
LEFT JOIN  ft_obl   ON ft_obl.id = t.subobl
LEFT JOIN  ft_otr   ON ft_otr.id = t.subotr
```

Comment: Изменение IN на OR ничего не дало вообще, ни время выполнения ни EXPLAIN не изменился.

По поводу более раннего JOIN, вот вывод собственно самого EXPLAIN
 
>`id|select_type| table |type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows| Extra 
 1|  SIMPLE |ft_ttopic| ALL |  NULL   | NULL | NULL |NULL|132 |Using temporary; Using filesort
 1|  SIMPLE | ft_user | ALL |  NULL   | NULL | NULL |NULL|1264|Using join buffer
 1|  SIMPLE |  ft_obl | ALL |  NULL   | NULL | NULL |NULL|263 |Using where; Using join buffer
 1|  SIMPLE |  ft_otr |eq_ref|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|  2  |ft_ttopic.tpotr|1 |Using where`

Comment: Нужно больше информации... Зачем вам вообще группировка??

Comment: @yarnik Если Вы хотите существенно дополнить вопрос, правильно его отредактировать, вместо добавления комментария.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас новость отображается даже если юзер подписан на область (например №2), а новость принадлежит к городу другой области (например №8, область №6).
создал новую тему с более простым вариантом (без отраслей) под названием  "Оптимизация кода 2"

Answer (score -5):

1. Старайся как можно меньше (а то и совсем) использовать JOIN.
2. Я, например, никогда не использую этот оператор и принцип хранения и сбора данных из БД - "ключ- значение". В твоем случае - лучше сделать несколько запросов к БД, чем один, но такой. Такие запросы еще можно делать каким-либо индексатором (Сфинкс, например) и то - не желательно.

Comment: только путем перемножения отраслей и областей получаем  ~ 60 тыс запросов, поэтому я думаю что этот вариант все же лучше, он сразу все выводит

Comment: Думаю, что у Вас кривая организация БД.
Ну блин, учесть то, что на мои сервера получают ежесекундно более 8.000 запросов, не менее 6000 из которых попадают в БД + пользователи, которые генерируют различного рода контент (начиная от статистики по данным от месяца и до года) свои данные получают не позже, чем через 1-10 секунд.... могу твердо сказать - у Вас хреновая реализация того, что Вы сейчас имеете.

Comment: @Станислав Комар, 8000 запросов... Вы либо преувеличиваете либо не говорите всех условий..... В среднем, сервер не сможет обслужить 10к средних запросов....

Comment: думаю сервер то сможет (средний даже) а вот какой-нибудь шаред хостинг нет

Comment: тут упор на средний запрос ( для конкретики - страница каталога магазина из 3х таблиц - доступность, товары, поставщики ), без кеширования.

Comment: В такой формулировке совет весьма сомнителен.